# Does R separate_wider_regex allow use of the multiline regex flag (?m) or regex(..., multiline=TRUE)?

Tags: r, tidyr, multiline

I am trying to replace the deprecated tidyr::extract with tidyr::separate_wider_regex.
However, I am separating a multiline text column and it seems that separate_wider_regex does not respect the multiline regex flag (?m) or the related regex(..., multiline=TRUE) function.

MWE:

```
tibble(x = 'a\nmultiline\ntext') %>% 
separate_wider_regex(x, c('(?m).*?', m='(?m)multiline', '(?m).*'))
```

> Error in `separate_wider_regex()`:   Expected each value of `x` to
> match the pattern, the whole pattern, and nothing but the pattern.   1
> value has problem.   Use `too_few = "debug"` to diagnose the problem.
> Use `too_few = "start"` to silence this message.   Run
> `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

in contrast,

```
str_match('a\nmultiline\ntext', '(?m)multiline')
```

yields the expected

```
     [,1]       
[1,] "multiline"
```

Thanks for the help!

I have also tried playing with adding/removing (?m) flags, replacing with the regex(..., multiline=TRUE), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `patterns` parameter of `separate_wider_regex()` [states](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html):

> *patterns*
>
> A named character vector where the names become column names and the
> values are regular expressions that match the contents of the vector.
> Unnamed components will match, but not be included in the output.

What it maybe *should* say is:

> [...] the values are regular expressions that match the **entire** contents of the vector.

The [function](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/0764e65fad777b71aa2a81ffd5447d04a61f8d5e/R/separate-wider.R#LL416C1-L416C1) adds a `^` onto the beginning, and a `$` onto the end of your pattern, meaning it either *all* of it matches, or *none* of it does.

The short version of why the regex you posted doesn't work is because the dot character doesn't match newlines.

The long version is, well, to help me explain, here is a working version of your code:

```
tibble(x = "a\nmultiline\ntext") %>%
  separate_wider_regex(x, c(a = "(?m).*?", "\n", b='(?m)multiline', "\n", c='(?m).*'), too_few = "debug")

# a     b         c     x                    x_ok  x_matches x_remainder
#  <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr>                <lgl>     <int> <chr>      
# 1 a     multiline text  "a\nmultiline\ntext" TRUE          5 ""
```

All that `?m` does it enable you to use `^` and `$` to find the start and end of a line respectively. In other words, you can replace `b='(?m)multiline'` with `b='(?m)^.*$'` or `b='multiline'`, and it'll return the same thing.

To match *across* newlines (i.e. to have `.` match newlines too), use `(?s)`

```
# this is maybe what you had in mind:

tibble(x = "a\nmultiline\ntext") %>%
  separate_wider_regex(x, c(a = "(?s).*?",b='multiline', c='(?s).*'), too_few = "debug")

# A tibble: 1 × 7
#  a     b         c        x                    x_ok  x_matches x_remainder
#  <chr> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>                <lgl>     <int> <chr>      
# 1 "a\n" multiline "\ntext" "a\nmultiline\ntext" TRUE          3 ""
```

Final note: for anyone in the future reading this who is stumped by this function: use the `too_few = "debug"` parameter! It helped me a lot in debugging this, in particular in showing me when something matched part of the text, but not the whole thing. Truly a godsend!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  The multiline flag (?m) is supposed to allow matching across newlines, as it does with my str_match example.  See the regular expression description in the stringr documentation for a description of the multiline flag.  The actual problem would seem to be that the separate_wider_regex code adds "^" to the front and "$" to the end of the combined regex.  With the multiline flag, ^ matches the beginning of each line, and $ matches the end of each line.  With multiline, \A and \Z replace the functionality of the usual ^ and $ anchors.

Comment: @DanWilt I just looked through the stringr documentation, and I couldn't see it. Whereabouts did you see `(?m)` matching newlines?

Comment: I just see this: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html?q=multiline#anchors

Comment: It doesn't mention (?m) which is the conventional flag for multiline, but other R regex functions recognize it.  Thinking that flag might not work, I tried the mentioned regex(..., multiline=TRUE) which doesn't work either.

Comment: yeah, `multiline=TRUE`, and `(?m)` do the same thing. There doesn't appear to be good documentation of flags in the docs, nor anywhere else sadly. I just found examples in other people's answers on StackOverflow